# Como validar um Registro de médico CRM?

Tags: api, validação

Preciso validar uma informação para determinar se o usuário do meu sistema é um médico ou um paciente, neste caso o CRM, e gostaria de saber se existe alguma API gratuita que valide ou algum padrão que eu possa seguir para identificar se é ou não um CRM válido, assim como fazemos com CPF.

Comment: Viu o [Consulta CRM](http://www.consultacrm.com.br/index/api)?

Comment: @vnbrs vi sim, ele disponibiliza 100 consultas gratuitas, o que não vai suprir a minha demanda.

Comment: Amigo, o Conselho Regional de Medicina disponibiliza esse serviço para que instituições públicas e privadas possam verificar se um médico é realmente um médico ou está falsificando seu registro. Se eles disponibilizam um WebService gratuito você deve perguntar diretamente a eles.

Comment: @CelsoLívero eu perguntei no http://portal.cfm.org.br/ mas não responderam...

Comment: a consulta ao CRM, não vai te trazer apenas se é válido ou não irá te trazer o nome, profissão, e status (válido / expirado / inválido) por isso eles cobram. tente novamente, eles devem achar que você quer todas essas informações, veja se não tem só como validar se o numero é correto.

Comment: veja, procurei um amigo meu que é médico pelo nome dele no http://www.cremesp.org.br/ (CRM - SP) e pelo que eu vi no numero dele não tem digito verificador, ou seja, é só um ID autoincremento em um banco de dados impresso em uma carterinha

Comment: @GabrielRodrigues como você resolveu isso?

Answer (score 9):

Validação por dígito verificador, semelhante ao CPF, não é possível. Como já foi mencionado nos comentários, o CRM é apenas um número sequencial.

Há algum tempo, havia feito a consulta pelo portal. Navegava até uma URL:

```
http://portal.cfm.org.br/index.php?medicosNome=mario&medicosUF=ES&medicosCRM=&medicosSituacao=&medicosTipoInscricao=&medicosEspecialidade=&medicosAreaAtuacao=&captcha=wg76pm&buscaEfetuada=true&option=com_medicos#buscaMedicos
```

E percorria a tabela de resultados (em html). Porém, agora colocaram um Captcha. Ainda assim é possível fazer esse processo, mas como não havia demanda, também não perdi tempo com isso.

Como você mencionou nos comentários também, tentou utilizar o `http://www.consultacrm.com.br/index/api` porém é limitado a 100 consultas.

Eu, faria o seguinte:

Criar a interface para o consultaCrm, e deixe que o usuário informe a chave da API, então você passa a ter 100 consultas por usuário. Na sua interface, você pode direcionar o usuário para a página de registro e geração da chave, facilitando o processo.